# Правильно объединить временные запросы в mysql

Tags: mysql

В *MYSQL* у меня есть таблица *Events*, в которой есть параметры:

- дата начало=start
- дата конец=end
- текст=small_desc
- каждый год=repeat, и др.

Мне нужно объединить два разных запроса:

1. Вывод следующих десяти событий с настоящей даты это не сложно - `SELECT * FROM events WHERE start >= :start.`
2. Вывод событий, за все время с параметром `repeat = 1`, то есть, повторять каждый год (например это дни рождения) в те же десять событий, но со дня следующего или равному сегодняшнему без учета года. 
   `:start=Дата сегодня`

Делаю так:

```
SELECT * FROM events AS one WHERE `repeat`=1 AND DAY(`start`)>=DAY(:start)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM events AS two WHERE`start` >= :start)
ORDER BY `start` ASC LIMIT 10
```

Но выходит все по прошлому году не включая этот.

Comment: Какой год у ежегодного(`repeat`=1) события в поле `start` ?

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь! Любой год. Вообще с 15 используется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` совершенно ни к чему, можно использовать `OR` в условиях, главное не забывать скобки, дабы он не приводил к неожиданным результатам. Если будете добавлять еще условия в запрос, весь блок проверки дат стоит заключить в скобки. А `DAY()` возвращает только номер дня, а нам нужен день и месяц, будем использовать `date_format`. В принципе есть еще `dayofyear()`, но в високосных и не високосных годах, после февраля она выдает разные результаты.

```
SELECT * FROM events
 WHERE (`repeat`=1 AND date_format(`start`,'%m%d') >= date_format(:start,'%m%d'))
    OR `start` >= :start
 ORDER BY date_format(`start`,'%m%d') ASC LIMIT 10
```

А теперь совсем правильный ответ :) С учетом того, что при поиске в декабре, январские дни рождения предыдущий запрос не выберет. Т.е. по хорошему нам всегда надо видеть все дни рождения, только те, которые в предыдущих днях года от текущего должны считаться событиями следующего года.

```
  select *
    from events
   where (`repeat`=1 OR `start` >= :start)
   order by if(`repeat`=1,date(concat(if(date_format(`start`,'%m%d')<date_format(:start,'%m%d'),1,0)+year(:start),date_format(`start`,'%m%d'))),`start`)
   limit 10
```

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь! Да все верно в плане repeat, не тогда не выводятся события этого года без этого условия.

Comment: @Resmedia Почему не выводятся, OR же работает

Comment: Возможно может нужно условие сделать, что бы не более 5 из каждого варианта показывалось, а то он все 10 забивает только условием `repeat`=1

Comment: @Resmedia Логично ... если те дни рождения предыдущего года то в сортировке они на первом месте ... Можно попробовать сделать `ORDER BY  date_format(`start`,'%m%d')`

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ!!! Работает.

Comment: @Resmedia Вообще у вас в декабре проблемы будут, январские дни рождения же ДО декабря и пока январь не наступит они не покажутся. Если придумаю как решить проблему тут допишу в ответе ...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.

Comment: @Resmedia Сделал совсем правильный вариант

Comment: спасибо, супер!

Answer (score 0):

Если речь про год, то стоит использовать функцию `DAYOFYEAR`, т.е.

```
SELECT * FROM events AS one WHERE `repeat`=1 AND DAYOFYEAR(`start`)>=DAYOFYEAR(:start)
```

При этом Вы можете объединить запросы без `union` и вытащить все одним запросом

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE (`repeat`=1 AND DAYOFYEAR(`start`)>=DAYOFYEAR(:start)) or (`start`>=:start))
```

Но если говорить про оптимизацию, это крайне плохой пример запроса, т.к. перед выборкой требуется вычислять значение для каждой строки и нет возможности использовать индексы. Поэтому я бы рекомендовал добавить колонки `StartDayOfYear` и `EndDayOfYear`, в которые класть значения соответствующих дней года и для `repeat=1` выбирать значения именно по этим полям.

Comment: Спасибо за желание помочь! Но Ваш метод к сожалению не сработал.