# Хранение только дня и месяца

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, которая хранит праздники.

Как правильно хранить день и месяц праздника в таблице? Чтобы, допустим, знать, что 31.12 каждого года — новый год. Если я внесу 31.12.2016 в базу и подпишу, что это новый год, я думаю, это будет неправильно. Как через год система сверит с базой, что на данный момент НГ будет уже 31.12.2017?

Comment: Мне кажется их будет проще хранить вообще строкой MMDD и текущий год приклеивать. а то довольно муторно с ними работать. можете еще посмотреть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482176/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-mysql/482224#482224

Comment: А если апдейтить с каждым годом год у всех праздников на текущий?

Comment: Да можно и так в принципе. просто раз в год можно забыть это сделать. Ежегодное задание в крон класть что ли :) причем это надо сделать точно в 0:00 1 января, когда вы вряд ли полезете проверять отработал ли скрипт :) И все ли апдейтить отдельный вопрос, праздники периодически меняются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как рекомендуют, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998534/4827341), лучше дату хранить именно как дату.

а чтобы не было проблем с сохранением даты 29 февраля, использовать год `0004` (високосный), а не `0000` (не високосный).

правда, предлагаемый там алгоритм получения даты в текущем году как раз на 29-м февраля и «хромает»:

```
mysql> select adddate(subdate(date('0004/02/29'),interval 4 year),interval year(now()) year) as data;
+------------+
| data       |
+------------+
| 2016-02-28 |
+------------+
```

я же предлагаю сразу прибавлять текущий год, уменьшенный на четыре:

```
mysql> select adddate(date('0004/02/29'),interval year(now())-4 year) as data; 
+------------+
| data       |
+------------+
| 2016-02-29 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую ваш вариант!