# Запрос с выборкой дат

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день.

Мне надо в БД хранить информацию о событиях. Выводить ее надо одним списком с сортировкой по датам. Но вопрос в том, что события бывают разовые (у них есть конкретная дата), и периодически повторяющиеся (Например, ежегодные).

Я изначально планировал все события хранить в одной таблице, и просто в одном из полей указывать тип события (разовое, ежемесячной, ежегодное). Но сейчас понимаю, что сделать выборку с сортировкой по датам не смогу, если событие привязано к дате годовалой давности (ежегодное).

Вторая мысль была в том, чтобы сделать разные таблицы для разных типов событий (разовые, ежедневные, еженедельные, ежемесячные, ежегодные). Но тогда "сборку" единой ленты придется делать полностью внутри программы точно.

Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей? Как лучше реализовать эту базу? Самый идеальный вариант при выборке не учитывать год, то такой запрос написать, предполагаю, не получится (или, по крайней мере, я не понимаю как).

Спасибо.

Comment: Вот что то похожее было (правда там периодичность только годовая) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482176/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-mysql/482224#482224   P.S. Запросов "_которые написать не получиться_" не бывает, бывают только запросы, написание или время работы которых не стоят решаемой задачи

Comment: Спасибо. Это, скорее всего, то, что надо. Я думал, что DATE_FORMAT нельзя использовать в блоке WHERE, и он меняет только формат вывода. Сейчас попробую сделать как там написано.

Comment: Второй вариант там более правильный. хотя конечно от решаемой задачи зависит. Для получения скорых событий в районе 30 декабря по простому уловию все события с месяц-день больше текущего не даст должного эффекта, потому как январь меньше. Поэтому там во втором варианте я решил выбирать ежегодные события вообще всегда, просто сортировка там организована кольцом от текущей даты. хотя при желании, можно и в where кольцо организовать, если задача например "выбрать на 30 дней вперед"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать две таблицы:

1. Даты возникновения событий:

   - дата/время возникновения события
   - ссылка на описание события
2. Описание событий:

   - наименование
   - периодичность
   - дата/время начала периода
   - дата/время окончания периода
   - прочие данные

При возникновении событий в дату/время из первой таблицы пересчитываем следующие события на основе данных из второй таблицы и добавляем их в первую таблицу.

Проблема возникнет только если потребуется отображение календаря событий. Но она тоже решается выборкой описаний на тот месяц (или иной период, который будет отображен в календаре) и пересчетом событий для первой таблицы (дубликаты естественно не нужно добавлять).